# É incorreto dizer "gratuito" com tônica no "i"?

Tags: pronúncia, diferenças

Eu particularmente acho que soa melhor "gratu**í**to" (com tônica no `i`), e também ouço muita gente dizer assim. Porém também muitas vezes ouço "grat**ú**ito" (com tônica no `u`), principalmente nos programas e jornais de televisão.

Procurei nos dicionários pela separação das sílabas, e vi que é `gra-tui-to`. A sílaba tônica padrão do português é a paroxítona, portanto a pronúncia seria "gra**túi**to". Só seria "gratu**í**to" se fosse `gra-tu-i-to`. Para confirmar, vi no Priberam e lá especifica que é `úi`.

Sendo assim, é realmente incorreto dizer "gratu**í**to"?

Comment: Se a separação fosse gra-tu-i-to, seria necessário um acento agudo no i, já que haveria um hiato tônico, não é? Este parece ser o motivo para que se pronuncie gra-tui-to.

Comment: Creio que em Portugal a pronúncia mais comum é precisamente gra-tu-í-to, a errada. Vou passar a dizer gra-tui-to e ver como as pessoas reagem.

Comment: Muitas vezes eu coloco aqui como resposta aquilo que o uso popular consagrou.  Eu falo "gra**tui**to com a silába tônica em "tui" e a maioria dos brasileiros com instrução secundária e superior também.

Comment: Em Portugal usa-se apenas a pronúncia correcta. Nunca ouvi a que menciona o @Jacinto.

Comment: @Jonas, podes nunca ter ouvido gra-tu-í-to, mas essa pronúncia é comum em Portugal. A equipa do dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003) regista-a, "a pronúncia popular *gratuíto*, comum em Portugal e em alguns lugares do Brasil" [...]; o pessoal do [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/artigos/rubricas/idioma/gratuito-periodo-madail-juiz/1856) também; e é a minha pronúncia e da maior parte dos meus amigos.

Comment: @Jacinto Sim, muita gente usa essa pronúncia incorrecta, mas há que aprender a falar correctamente.

Comment: @Jonas, então a tua primeira afirmação é falsa! (Que em Portugal se usa apenas a pronúncia "correta", três comentários acima.)

Comment: @Jacinto É de facto como eu digo, explico novamente: só conta o que se fala correctamente. E de facto não é comum falar incorrectamente em Portugal, mas quando se houve essa palavra inexistente "gratuíto" há apenas que corrigir o falante.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/gratuito), o [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/gratuito), a [Infopédia](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/gratuito); todos dizem que não há hiato, como de resto em *circuito*, *intuito*, *fortuito*, mas também casos parecidos como *fluido*, *descuido* e *muito* (mas ao contrário do nome *arguido*, que provavelmente se pronuncia com hiato porque provém do particípio de *arguir*).

A minha avaliação de qual é a pronúncia mais comum difere daquela do Jacinto. Conheço meia dúzia de pessoas que pronunciam /u-i/ (a maioria das quais nem são de Lisboa), mas estão claramente em minoria no meu círculo social.

Comment: Penso que existem fluido e fluído (flui-do e flu-i-do), a primeira tendendo a ser usada mais como adjetivo (*a situação política está flui-da*) e a segunda como substantivo, principalmente para designar a substância que se incendeia nos isqueiros (*flu-í-do de isqueiro*).

Answer (score 3):

*Gratuito* tem um ditongo em *ui*, portanto o correto é pronunciar gratuito (úi).

Se fosse hiato, teria o acento no "i", como ocorre em *saída*.

No dicionário Aurélio que tenho, sinaliza o "ui" de gratuito como (úi).

Aqui no Brasil também acabo ouvindo a pronúncia *gratu-í-to*

Comment: No Brasil o ensino do idioma é precário. O comum é falarem gra.tu.í.to. Como sabemos, o correto seria a pronúncia gra.tui.to, como for.tui.to, in.tui.to. Mas pode ser pior, pois falam flu.í.do na maioria das vezes.

Comment: @AndréLyra Não só por conta do ensino de português nas escolas, mas também de parte do pessoal dos meios de comunicação que não se atentam nem à pronúncia correta

Comment: Circuito sofre de dois problemas, a pronúncia cir.cu.í.to é um deles, rara, somente iniciando frases. O outro problema é que inclusive inventaram a palavra cir.qüi.to derivada dessa pronúncia. Foneticamente ela é interessante, mas não existe de acordo com os que definem o que existe na língua.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui há uma análise e explicação linguística interessante sobre o tema - mostra que quem impôs a pronúncia gratúito, "proibindo" gratuíto com base no latim, na verdade cometeu um erro, e gratuíto seria a pronúncia preferível: https://dicionarioegramatica.com.br/2017/06/13/gratuito-ou-gratuito-quem-corrigia-e-que-estava-errado/

Comment: Bom dia André. Poderias copiar trechos relevantes do link citado e adicioná-los aqui? Assim a relevância da sua resposta se mantém, mesmo que o link venha a deixar de existir no futuro.

Comment: André, o dicionário Houaiss tem uma nota relevante sobre o assunto: "**gratuito** [...] é da tradição culta fazer incidir a tónica sobre o *-u-*, uso fundado nos registos latinos *gratuìtus* e *fortuìtus*; a rectificação para *gratuītus* e *fortuītus* (Ernoult e Meillet) [o ī "justificaria" a pronúncia *gratuíto*] é relativamente recente, não podendo por isso alterar o padrão já consagrado (ver o it. *gratuito* e *fortuito*); a pronúncia popular *gratuíto*, comum em Portugal e em alguns lugares do Brasil (esp. São Paulo), não pode ser imputada ao étimo latino [...]"

Comment: Sua informação é muito relevante e importante para aumentar a qualidade das respostas dessa pergunta. Por isso, reforço o pedido do @gmauch, adicione como citação o trecho do link já informado por ti.

Comment: @gmauch - As partes relevantes parecem ser, *“gratuito” em latim não era grātuĭtus, com a marcação curva que indicaria que o “i” era breve, mas sim grātuītus, com o marcador reto que indicava que o “i” era longo. Ou seja: a pronúncia correta em latim (e isso pode ser hoje conferido em qualquer livro de latim) era gratuítus, com ênfase no “i”, e não gratúitus, com ênfase no “u”*... (continua)

Comment: ...e também *o português não veio diretamente do latim, mas sim do galego, teria também servido darem uma olhada em nossa língua-mãe: em galego, até hoje, a pronúncia (e a grafia) oficial é gratuíto (ver aqui), e não o gratúito dos puristas equivocados.*

Comment: O "ver aqui" do comentário anterior refere-se a este linque, http://academia.gal/dicionario?p_p_id=dictionarynormalsearch_WAR_BUSCARAGFrontendportlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-2&p_p_col_count=1&_dictionarynormalsearch_WAR_BUSCARAGFrontendportlet_miniSearchNoun=gratuito - em que de fato se vê que para a Real Academia Galega o correto é *gratuíto* com acento e tônica no *i*...

Comment: @LuísHenrique, a idéia é ter estas relevantes informações no corpo da resposta de maneira que alguém apenas lendo-a, sem precisar acessar outro link, ou ler os comentários, tenha a explicação completa. Podes editar a resposta e adicionar suas citações?